# move parenthesis to comment in local range in Microsoft Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to move all the text I have in parenthesis to a comment in a range I select. I am almost there but for some reason it only works at the start of the range. My macro is as follows:

```
Sub CommentOutParenthsLocal()
'
' CommentBubble Macro
'
'
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection.Range
searchText = "\(*\)"

With myRange.Find
    .MatchWildcards = True
    Do While .Execute(findText:=searchText, Forward:=True) = True
      ActiveDocument.Comments.Add myRange, myRange.Text
      myRange.Text = ""
    Loop
 End With
End Sub
```

Any advice?

Comment: Weird... I copied your code and tested. It worked for multiple instance of your search criteria, *"\(*\)"*. This moves the identified text to the Comment pane, then deletes the original text, aside leaving the first, *\*. Only thing I noticed is you're not using **Option Explicit** statement which would force you to declare *searchText.* - which I see is not here.... Let me know after you **Dim searchText as String**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you need to limit your code's scope to what you've actually selected, amongst other things. In that case, try:

```
Sub CommentOutParenthsLocal()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection.Range
With Selection.Range
  With .Find
    .Text = "\(*\)"
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found = True
    If .InRange(myRange) = False Then Exit Do
    .Comments.Add .Duplicate, .Text
    .Text = vbNullString
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: but why isn’t selection.range in my code enough? Why do you need to check if it’s InRange again?

Comment: Because the selected range constantly changes when using Find and will simply continue finding past the end of your selection.

Comment: Wow, that’s confusing as the outer loop starts with selection.range. It dynamically updates the variable value.